# Cannot store value in inputfield to check if it is correct. unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey guys (sorry to ask a question again so soon).

I was trying to create an input field, and whenever the player types in something correct it would register as being correct. My tactic for this was to create a string (for the text that displays a question or dialogue), and then create another string with the answers. If the specific answer 'point' (in the range e.g. '1', '2', '3' and the user wrote '3' when it was the 3rd point) was correct, as in the example, then it would go green and move on. 
Like with using buttons, I planned on making an int variable and having that reset when something went in. Upon trying this though I found many problems. If I tried to make it with another string attached to another object and verified if the two were equal, the second I wrote the answer (without pressing enter), it would register instead of afterwards. I presume this is because the console is not registering it after the click. 
So I tried experimenting with another text box. The textbox would have the answer as well, and if the text that the user wrote in the inputfield matched that it would go on. The problem with this is that apparently you cannot refer to an inputfield and a text in the same statement. So this is where, 4 hours later, I come to you guys. Is there a way in which I can store the value of the inputfield and check it with the text of something else to see if it was correct?

my code: hello and by were the two text UIs I tried to use in order to help with the verification process, although I presume that if you did this properly there is a better way to do it. This is the controller, that is connected to an empty game object with the inputfield connected to the inputfield (within the object).

```
             using  System.Collections;
             using System.Collections.Generic;
             using UnityEngine;
             using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

List<string> answers = new List<string>() { "1", "1", "1", "1", "1" };
public static string answer;
public Text hello;
public Text by;



// Allows you to attach the inputfield to the game controller, saving code
[SerializeField]
// declare variable input
private InputField input;

 void Start()
{
    hello = GameObject.Find("Hi").GetComponent<Text>();
    by = GameObject.Find("Bye").GetComponent<Text>();



}
// registers what the user writes 
public void getInput(string guess)
{
    // Declares the value in the console 
    input.text = "";



    Debug.Log("Hi");





}
```

This is the code for the main text with the dialogue:

```
public class inputTextControl : MonoBehaviour {


List<string> questions = new List<string>() { "This is the first question", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" };

public  static string input = "n";
public static int randInput = -1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    if (randInput == -1)
    {
        // The range of questions that can be asked (all the strings need to match this range for the questions in order to be functional without an exception error 
        randInput = Random.Range(0, 5);
    }

    if (randInput > -1)
    {
        GetComponent<Text>().text = questions[randInput];
    }


           }



            }
```

I apologise if I am not being that clear..it's just really hard for me to explain the whole situation, apart from the fact that instead of the inputfield working like a 'type in the right answer' and if you are wrong you lose, it is just not working at all.

Have a good weekend!

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `GetComponent<>()` is an expensive operation and you shouldn't ever need to call it in Update() function. Declare it in the Start() function (same  way as 'hello' or 'by')

Second, I suggest you to drag all public variables in editor so you won't even need to use GetComponent in the start function (it will make your scripts more clean).

Thirdly, you don't need to explicitly get Text component to get the value of the input field. `inputF.text` does the job. See example at the end for more information.

Finally, your question is:

**Q:**Is there a way in which I can store the value of the inputfield and check it with the text of something else to see if it was correct?

**A:** Yes. Here is a quick example.

```
public InputField input;

void Start(){
    // Following line can be dismissed if we drag our input field in editor
    input = GameObject.Find("AnswerInputFieldName").GetComponent<InputField>();
}

void CheckAnswer(){
    string correct = "correctAnswer";
    string userAnswer = input.text;
    if(correct.compare(userAnswer) == 0)
        Debug.Log("That's correct!");
}
```

Call CheckAnswer() function whenever you feel you need it.

P.S. If you want to instantly check if answer is correct you don't need to do call CheckAnswer() in Update because it is called each frame for no reason. You need to call it whenever input field value has changed. Google more about event listeners.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes total sense. Firstly, I guess I was not searching the correct thing on google, and also I did solve this problem eventually using a class to define the text and then making an if statement, but I presume your one (having the == 0) clears the inputfield after someone clicks enter (which mine currently does not do)

Comment: That `if(correct.compare(userAnswer) == 0)` statement only compares if two strings are equal or not. It doesn't clear the input field. To do so, you need to set input field to empty string : `input.text=""`

Comment: Ye I figured it out yesterday! Thank you so much for all of your help